# Javascript alert box is hidden inside popup window

Tags: javascript, overflow, alert, hidden, box

[Hidden alert box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWTj3.png)

OS : Windows 7 32-bit
Browser : Google Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m

Like the attached screenshot,
alert box's overflowed area is hidden inside popup window.
It happens only in Chrome 32-bit.
Anyone had this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal behaviour for Chrome.

Given that internally the dialog is also just composed of HTML and CSS (pretty much everything UI related in Chrome is), it doesn't come as a surprise that the window's content won't overflow the window. It's no native OS dialog or similar.

Comment: No, that's not normal. Because 64bit Chrome works fine.